# Polly retry request with different request-body

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic, httpclientfactory

I have never used Polly before and am not sure if this is a good scenario for Polly.

I am calling an endpoint with a list of 1000 `DTO` in the `POST` body. Now the endpoint will perform some validations on each `DTO` and return a HTTP 400 Bad Request if any of those DTOs fail validation, and the response will also contain the `id` of all the `DTO`s that failed validation. So, even if one `DTO` fails validation, I get and HTTP 400 response.

Now I was wondering if I can handle this gracefully for the remaining DTOs that passed the validation.

So, whenever I get a HTTP 400 from the API, I want to change the request payload to remove the `DTO`s that caused validation failure and retry the request with the remaining `DTO`s.

How can I achieve this with Polly?

I am using a typed `HttpClient` using `HttpClientFactory` in .NET 5 to make my `POST` requests.

Comment: *Polly* is seemingly ***not*** the right tool for the job here (even if you could possibly get it to work). It would be easier to use *Polly* for transient faults etc, and then write some simple C# logic to do the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polly's retry policy performs the **exact same operation** whenever it triggers. So, by the default you can't alter the request.

But you can modify it in the `onRetryAsync` delegate, which is fired before the actual retry happens.

---

In order to demonstrate this I will use the [WireMock.NET](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net) library to mimic your downstream system.

So, first let's create a webserver, which listens on the `40000` port on the `localhost` at the `/api` route:

```
protected const string route = "/api";
protected const int port = 40_000;

protected static readonly WireMockServer server = WireMockServer.Start(port);
protected static readonly IRequestBuilder endpointSetup = Request.Create().WithPath(route).UsingPost();
```

Then setup a [scenario](http://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/) to simulate that the first request fails with 400 and then the second succeeds with 200.

```
protected const string scenario = "polly-retry-test";
```

```
server.Reset();
server
    .Given(endpointSetup)
    .InScenario(scenario)
    .WillSetStateTo(1)
    .WithTitle("Failed Request")
    .RespondWith(Response.Create().WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));

server
    .Given(endpointSetup)
    .InScenario(scenario)
    .WhenStateIs(1)
    .WithTitle("Succeeded Request")
    .RespondWith(Response.Create().WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK));
```

Let's test it

```
protected static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

```
var result = await client.PostAsync($"http://localhost:{port}{route}", new StringContent(""));
Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);

result = await client.PostAsync($"http://localhost:{port}{route}", new StringContent(""));
Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);
```

the output will be the following:

```
BadRequest
OK
```

---

Okay, so now we have a downstream simulator, now it's time to focus on the retry policy. For the sake of simplicity I'll serialize a `List<int>` collection to post it as the payload.

I setup the retry whenever it receives a 400 then in its `onRetryAsync` delegate I examine the response and remove the unwanted integers.

```
AsyncRetryPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> retryInCaseOfPartialSuccess = Policy
    .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
    .RetryAsync(1, onRetryAsync: (dr, _, __) => {

        //TODO: Process response from: `dr.Result.Content`
        //TODO: Replace the removal logic to appropriate one
        dtoIds.RemoveAt(0);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
```

Let's call the downstream API with the decorated retry policy:

```
await retryInCaseOfPartialSuccess.ExecuteAsync(async (_) => {
    var payload = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dtoIds);
    Console.WriteLine(payload); //Only for debugging purposes
    return await client.PostAsync($"http://localhost:{port}{route}", new StringContent(payload));
}, CancellationToken.None);
```

---

Let's put all this together:

```
protected const string scenario = "polly-retry-test";
protected const string route = "/api";
protected const int port = 40_000;
protected static readonly WireMockServer server = WireMockServer.Start(port);
protected static readonly IRequestBuilder endpointSetup = Request.Create().WithPath(route).UsingPost();
protected static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

private static async Task Main()
{
    server.Reset();
    server
        .Given(endpointSetup)
        .InScenario(scenario)
        .WillSetStateTo(1)
        .WithTitle("Failed Request")
        .RespondWith(Response.Create().WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));

    server
        .Given(endpointSetup)
        .InScenario(scenario)
        .WhenStateIs(1)
        .WithTitle("Succeeded Request")
        .RespondWith(Response.Create().WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK));

    //var result = await client.PostAsync($"http://localhost:{port}{route}", new StringContent(""));
    //Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);

    //result = await client.PostAsync($"http://localhost:{port}{route}", new StringContent(""));
    //Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);

    await IssueRequestAgainstDownstream(new List<int> { 1, 2 });
}

private static async Task IssueRequestAgainstDownstream(List<int> dtoIds)
{
    AsyncRetryPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> retryInCaseOfPartialSuccess = Policy
        .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(response => response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        .RetryAsync(1, onRetryAsync: (dr, _, __) => {
            //TODO: Process response from: `dr.Result.Content`
            //TODO: Replace the removal logic to appropriate one
            dtoIds.RemoveAt(0);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });

    await retryInCaseOfPartialSuccess.ExecuteAsync(async (_) => {
        var payload = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dtoIds);
        Console.WriteLine(payload); //Only for debugging purposes
        return await client.PostAsync($"http://localhost:{port}{route}", new StringContent(payload));
    }, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

So, what we have done?

- Created a downstream mock to simulate 400 and 200 subsequent responses
- Created a retry policy which can amend the request's payload if it receives 400
- Put the serialization logic and the http call inside the retry, so, that we can always serialize the most recent list of objects